# How can I reduce amount of ifs and else ifs in this specific block of code?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I have some code in my loop that will determine the term in my custom taxonomy, if it's a specific term, it will output a specific image.

```
<?php if( has_term('10', 'review-score' ) ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
/images/review-scores-thumbs/10.jpeg" /> </a>
```

It works exactly how I want it to work, but after it, I have an else if for if the term is 9.5, 9, 8.5 ... 1. That's a lot of else ifs, and I'm not sure it will be good for my site's speed. To fix this, I was thinking of getting the term of the current post (I'm doing this inside a custom archive page loop), then doing something like this.

```
<?php $term = get_term($post->ID, 'review'score'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
/images/review-scores-thumbs/$term.jpeg" /> </a>
```

This would work given my jpegs are all named like that, but I'm having two problems. get_term is weird. I thought it would return only one term, but when I do this.

```
<?php $term = get_term($post->ID, 'review-score'); ?>
<?php if ($term = '10') { ?>
It worked
<?php } ?>
```

It displays it worked everywere even when the term is 9 or 8 for that specific thing.

Then in addition to this, it seems I cannot do

```
<?php $term = get_term($post->ID, 'review-score'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
/images/review-scores-thumbs/$term.jpeg" /> </a>
```

Because $term is in the quotes.

So, is what I'm doing possible? Is it even worth it (i.e., is using all those else ifs that bad)? And how does get_term work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong

- [`get_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) is the wrong function to use to get terms attached to a post. `get_term()` is used to get the term object from the db for a given term ID. The first parameter accepts the term ID, and not the post ID. You want to be using [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to get the terms attached to a post
- You really do not need any if/else statements here, simply pass the term ID/slug/name as image name depending on how your images are named. For the purpose of answering the eact examples as in OP, I have used the term id as image name. Change this to your exact needs.
- As already stated in another answer, you need `==` to compare two values, `=` assigns a value to another or to a variable

As you have stated `has_term()` works, so we can do the following then to solve the issue: (*I have written a function which you can add in functions.phpo and then call the function inside the loop where needed*)

**NOTE:**

All the code is untested and might be buggy. Be sure to test it on a test install with debug set to true. The code also requires a minimum of PHP 5.4

```
function get_term_related_image( $taxonomy = 'category' )
{
    // Invoke the global $post object
    global $post;

    // Check if we have a taxonomy and if it is valid, else return false
    if ( !$taxonomy )
        return false;    

    if ( $taxonomy !== 'category' )
        $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    // Get the terms assigned to the post
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    // Make sure we actually have terms, if not, return false
    if (    !$terms
         || is_wp_error( $terms )
    )
        return false;

    // Get the first term from the array of terms
    $term = $terms[0];

    // Get the image
    $image = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/review-scores-thumbs/' . $term->term_id . '.jpeg';

    // Check if we actually have an image before returning it
    if ( !getimagesize( $image ) ) 
       return false;

    // We have made it, YEAH!!!, return the image
    $permalink  = get_the_permalink( $post );
    $title_attr = the_title_attribute( ['echo' => false, 'post' => $post] );

    return '<a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . $title_attr . '"><img src="' . $image . '"/></a>';
}
```

**Inside** the loop, you can just call the function as follow: (*Just remember to pass the taxonomy name as first parameter if you are not using build in taxonomy `category`*)

```
echo get_term_related_image( 'review-score' );
```

### EDIT:

The code is now tested and works as expected

Comment: Please see my update, fix a few bugs, code is now working

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that get_term was wrong. $term->term_id didn't work for me, so I used what Tom recommended $term->slug, which worked like a charm. It was great thinking of doing this as a function. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: My pleasure, glad you resolved it. You should extend and modify the function as needed as I never know the exact usecase ;-). Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

First, let's grab the actual rating, `get_term` requires a term ID, which we don't have, so lets use `wp_get_object_terms` instead

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'review-score' );
```

The code so far has assumed there will be a single term, which is bad. But lets work with this assumption for the sake of this answer, and say that we're only dealing with the first term:

```
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $term = $terms[0];
```

`$terms` is a list of term objects, so lets make sure the list isn't empty, and that it's not an error. If it is, then we wan't to abort, and do something else.

Here `$term` is a variable that represents a `WP_Term` object, you're using the slug to hold the review score, so you need:

```
    $term->slug
```

You can look this up using the WordPress Codex and the official Developer Hub.

### Outputting the term

In PHP it's not enough to state the name of a variable in html, you have to echo it out, so this will not work:

```
<span>The term is: $term->slug </span>
```

You've not opened any PHP tags, so no PHP is executed, and you didn't put an echo statement to echo it out like this:

```
<span>The term is: <?php echo $term->slug; ?> </span>
```

With this information you should be able to correct your final code block to do what you want.

### Other Mistakes

```
<?php if ($var = '10') { ?>
```

Here you've made an assignment. The code reads "make $term equal to then, then that the making it 10 bit worked", so it's always true. Instead, use `==` which means equivalent, or `===` which means exactly equal to.

Instead I suggest swapping the order around:

```
<?php if ( '10' == $var ) {
```

This way if you accidentally type `=` instead of `==` it will generate a PHP error, rather than causing a hidden logic error, and the problem will be immediately obvious

Comment: `get_term()` uses the term id, not post id. `get_term()` is the wrong function to use here to get terms attached to a post

Comment: Good catch, updated the answer

Comment: $term-> slug worked great. Also, thanks for explaining the <?php ?> along with echoing. And I know == is the right way of doing it, but it was a typo. But great explanation, I will always remember that for why you cannot have = in anything conditional. I'm not sure if I knew that was the reason why...